# Django 1.6.5 - Unable to load initial data from fixtures

Tags: django-models, loaddata

I tried to load initial-data as suggested in [djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/). But I couldn't able to load object on my database. But when I tried to load data, it always says

```
> python manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/initial_data.json
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

But I have data on the initial_data.json [/test-project/tableTest/tableTest/fixtures/initial_data.json]

```
[
    {
        "model":"tableTest.person",
        "pk":1,
        "fields": {
            "name":"Kevin"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"tableTest.person",
        "pk":2,
        "fields": {
            "name":"Harry"
        }
    },
    {
        "model":"tableTest.person",
        "pk":3,
        "fields": {
            "name":"Piter"
        }
    }
]

#models.py
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="full name")
```

I also tried [./manage.py loaddata `pwd`/tableTest/fixtures/initial_data.json](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20933) but could not succeed. Please help me to suggest what I have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises because I write definition for model at project directory instead of app directory and Table I defined on model was not created on running `syncdb`. Later I create a app and move fixtures, models.py,views.py to app directory, rewrite urls.py. Then the data was loaded successfully.